# Get text from all spans in div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dynamically adding span elements to a div. I want to retrieve the text from all the span elements in the div at a later stage. How do I do this? I'd like to use jQuery, but Javascript is fine I guess.

Section of Javascript creating the span elements:

```
var x = ui.item.value;

var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML="       "+x+"";

$("#selected").append(span);
```

This is inside an on click event.
The div is called "selected".

Comment: you could just say `var text = $('#selected span').text()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
var txt= "";
    $("#selected span").each(function(){
        txt += $(this).text();//here you get the values from each span inside selected element
    });

$("body").append(txt);//here append the collected text inside e.g. body
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selected">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>   
</div>
```

Comment: This method works for me in a way. My span has it's own text, and then there is a button on the span that has it's own text. This method returns both the text of the span and the button. Also, the values are all added together, it's not in array form.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a `.each()` or any other loop. Just calling `.text()` will be enough since, according to the [**JQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/text/), it:

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

So:

```js
$("#selected").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("span").text();
    alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selected">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```